# Make package explicitly installed in pacman

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

I have a package that's installed on my PC as a dependency of another package.

I would like to have the package explicitly installed, but **without actually re-installing** it, or downloading any files.

Is this possible?

---

I do not have any packages cached in `/var/cache/pacman/pkg`, which is one of the reasons I want to change the package detail without a re-install.

Even If I had the packages cached, running `pacman -S <package>` would mean the whole install process is run, which I also want to avoid.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I found the answer on the [Arch Linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=825936#p825936).

Since pacman 3.4 you can use

```
# pacman -D
```

to modify *only* the database. So:

```
# pacman -D --asexplicit <pkgs>
```

will make `<pkgs>` **explicitly installed**.

The [`pacman` man page](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html#_database_options_apply_to_em_d_em_a_id_qo_a) further describes this command.

Answer (score 7):

`pacman -S` has a `--asexplicit` flag that should do what you want.

For example:

```
> pacman -Qi mutagen            
...
Install Reason : Installed as a dependency for another package

> pacman -S --asexplicit mutagen
warning: mutagen-1.20-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...

Targets (1): mutagen-1.20-1

Total Download Size:    0.00 MB
Total Installed Size:   0.82 MB
...

> pacman -Qi mutagen
...
Install Reason : Explicitly installed
```

You can see that nothing was downloaded since it is already installed locally. It just flipped the "Install Reason" field.

Pacman has different `--help` operations depending on the operation (`-S`, `-R`, etc.). So `pacman -S --help` lists the `--asexplicit` flag as one of the available flags. `--asdeps` is available as well.

Answer (score 0):

To install only if is not already installed you can use --needed flag:

```
pacman -S mutagen
pacman -S --needed mutagen clone
```

Will skip mutagen reinstalation if is already installed by the first command. And you will also get a nice info about that

Comment: This actually does not answer the question.