# Pacman/Arch: Install package(s) without really installing them

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make package explicitly installed in pacman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/make-package-explicitly-installed-in-pacman)

So I've been stupid and removed my /var/lib/pacman/local dir.
Without backup, but with a root shell open at tty4. 
O yeah, pacman -Sf  with the base repo also overwrites your /etc/passwd. Thank god for .pacorig.

I still have my pacman logs, but all the packages are already installed. Pacman outputs errors that the files already exist.
How can I install packages without modifying files? (pacman -S --fake --noextract)
I've also tried the -D switch but that only works for installed packages.

Comment: I don't know bout **not modifying files**. but you could force pacman to overwrite those files? `pacman -S --force`

Comment: I did, (pacman -Sf), but my system already runs for about 2 years so all the config files and changes would also be moved to .pacorig files. That is not what I want, I just need to tell pacman: screw what you think, I say this package is installed.